# Angular 8 Component View Pass Variable

Tags: angular

Question,

Is there a way to pass the MyObj to the #MyCustomTemplate

```
<div *ngFor="let t of MyObj.person">

          <3rdPartyComponent
           [customTemplate]="MyCustomTemplate"
           >
          </3rdPartyComponent>
</div>

<ng-template #MyCustomTemplate>
    MyObj
</ng-template>
```

Thanks,

Pong

Answer (score 0):

I don't exactly understand, are you iterating over an array of persons, that are on an object called MyObj? (so it should be `*ngFor="let t of MyObj.persons"`)

Also if you are using a 3rd party component, it really depends on the expected input of that specific component.

For a regular angular template, inserted using a template outlet, you can pass a variable like this:

```
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="myTemplate; context: { first: 1, second: 2}"></ng-container>

<ng-template #myTemplate let-xxx="second">
<h2>This is my template: {{ xxx }}</h2>
</ng-template>
```

Or if you iterating over an array and wishes to pass the current array item:

```
<div *ngFor="let person of MyObj.persons">
  <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="MyCustomTemplate; context: { data: person}"></ng-container>
</div>

<ng-template #MyCustomTemplate let-person="data">
    {{ person | json  }}
</ng-template>
```

working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3wljij